# EF LINQ to SQL, dividing by zero error, generated query puts parameters in wrong order

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

**EDIT** Steps to reproduce this error at bottom of post

My Data Structure for this issue:

```
    public class StockRequest
    {
        public int StartYear { get; set; }
        public StockInterval StockInterval { get; set; }
    }

    public class StockInterval
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Can be 0 = non-recurring, 1 = annual, 2 = once every 2 years, 3 = once every 3 years
        /// </summary>
        public int IntervalInYears { get; set; }
    }
```

If I want to get all stock requests for say 2021. The following data would meet that criteria:

```
var nonRecurringRequest = new StockRequest() { StartYear = 2021, StockInterval = new StockInterval() { IntervalInYears = 0 } };
var annualRequest = new StockRequest() { StartYear = 2020, StockInterval = new StockInterval() { IntervalInYears = 1 } };
var everyTwoYearsRequest = new StockRequest() { StartYear = 2019, StockInterval = new StockInterval() { IntervalInYears = 2 } };
var everyThreeYearsRequest = new StockRequest() { StartYear = 2018, StockInterval = new StockInterval() { IntervalInYears = 3 } };
```

The key where clause in the EF query is:

```
query.Where(x => 
   x.StartYear <= selectedYear && 
  (
    x.StartYear == selectedYear || 
    (x.StockInterval.IntervalInYears != 0 && selectedYear - x.StartYear % x.StockInterval.IntervalInYears == 0) 
  )
);
```

The part causing issues is a non-recurring stock request (interval of 0). You can't mod that because then you divide by zero. However, I'm aware of this and in the past have resolved this by first checking if the property (IntervalInYears) is not zero before trying to mod. Since the first part of the WHERE fails the check, it does not continue to the mod part.

For some reason that isn't working this time. And when I check the generated query, it's putting the 0 first:

```
WHERE 
StockRequests.[StartYear] <= @stockYear
AND 
(
    StockRequests.[StartYear] = @stockYear OR 
    (
        0 <> StockIntervals.[IntervalInYears] AND 
        0 = (@stockYear - StockRequests.[StartYear]) % StockIntervals.[IntervalInYears] 
    )
)
```

Executing that in SQL Server generates divide by zero error. However, flipping the sides of 0 and StockIntervals.IntervalInYears:

```
WHERE 
StockRequests.[StartYear] <= @stockYear
AND 
(
    StockRequests.[StartYear] = @stockYear OR 
    (
        StockIntervals.[IntervalInYears] <> 0  AND 
        0 = (@stockYear - StockRequests.[StartYear]) % StockIntervals.[IntervalInYears] 
    )
)
```

Now it works no problem. Why is EF switching this around and how can I fix it within EF? I didn't put the 0 first in the EF query and I don't recall this happening before, this was the solution I always used to make sure I wasn't trying to divide by zero and it used to work. I'm aware I could manually write the SQL query and execute that, but the projection is over 200 lines.

**EDIT**
To reproduce:
Table creation Scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StockIntervals](
[Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
[IntervalInYears] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.StockIntervals] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StockIntervals] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IntervalInYears]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StockRequests](
[Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[Count] [int] NOT NULL,
[DateRequested] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[StartYear] [int] NOT NULL,
[StockIntervalId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[EndYear] [int] NULL,


CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.StockRequests] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StockRequests]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.StockRequests_dbo.StockIntervals_StockIntervalId] FOREIGN KEY([StockIntervalId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[StockIntervals] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StockRequests] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.StockRequests_dbo.StockIntervals_StockIntervalId]
GO
```

Populate Tables:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[StockIntervals]
       ([Id]
       ,[Name]
       ,[IntervalInYears])
 VALUES
       ('738A431E-D517-4C17-9ECA-A1A0942E236B', 'Non-recurring one time', 0),
       ('CCB746A7-F644-4C7E-ADBE-AE14DE01B19E', 'Annual', 1),
       ('80C6CAE6-5287-41E6-A5FE-AAA53035EC19', 'Every 2 years', 2),
       ('B34EE256-C40B-4F03-8232-14B681186C7A', 'Every 3 years', 3)

GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[StockRequests]
       ([Id]
       ,[Count]
       ,[DateRequested]
       ,[StartYear]
       ,[StockIntervalId]
       ,[EndYear])
 VALUES
       ('4a5ae94e-0a85-4195-8e7e-8cc556307b30'
       ,15
       ,'2022-01-11 15:16:41.567'
       ,2021
       ,'738A431E-D517-4C17-9ECA-A1A0942E236B'
       ,null),
       ('f0d83b68-0da1-4824-9eeb-2e52ff369db5'
       ,60
       ,'2022-01-11 15:16:41.567'
       ,2020
       ,'CCB746A7-F644-4C7E-ADBE-AE14DE01B19E'
       ,null),
       ('a49b4b9e-80d6-4fca-ad78-6c8996616c97'
       ,1000
       ,'2022-01-11 15:16:41.567'
       ,2019
       ,'80C6CAE6-5287-41E6-A5FE-AAA53035EC19'
       ,null),
       ('cc21a265-f8df-4d2d-9eae-5f6f97ef9909'
       ,50
       ,'2022-01-11 15:16:41.567'
       ,2018
       ,'B34EE256-C40B-4F03-8232-14B681186C7A'
       ,null)
GO
```

Run this query:

```
DECLARE @stockYear int = 2021

SELECT * FROM 
dbo.StockRequests
INNER JOIN dbo.StockIntervals on StockIntervalId = StockIntervals.Id
WHERE 
    StockRequests.[StartYear] <= @stockYear
    AND 
    (
        StockRequests.[StartYear] = @stockYear OR 
        (
            0 <> StockIntervals.[IntervalInYears]  AND 
            0 = (@stockYear - StockRequests.[StartYear]) % StockIntervals.[IntervalInYears] 
        )
    )
```

No error. Okay now try inserting a new record:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[StockRequests]
VALUES ('FFA820F1-E361-4AC5-AB00-E621BFFEF9B5', 20, '2022-01-11 16:22:11.567', 2020, '738A431E-D517-4C17-9ECA-A1A0942E236B', null)
```

Run the query again. Divide by zero error happens. After playing with the data, this behavior makes sense. If the @stockYear is greater than or less than the `StartYear` and the interval of that record is zero, it will error out because if gets to the inner most part of the query, and the interval is zero and it doesn't have boolean expression shortcutting. Okay.

But switch the one line of the query to:

```
StockIntervals.[IntervalInYears] <> 0
```

Now it works! Not sure how this is coincidence though, I've run my scripts through many scenarios to trigger the error, but it always is resolved by the above. If there is no short cutting, switching the operands should still cause the error. Yet it does not, consistently. So people are saying the operand order doesn't matter, but I am able to show it appears to.

Comment: That's a database problem, not an EF problem. Which database are you using? In any case, this query is too complicated as is and EF already simplified it a bit. A 200-line query is *way* too complex to be written indirectly through LINQ. Apart from the simplification EF already performed, `0 = @stockYear - StockRequests.[StartYear] % StockIntervals.[IntervalInYears]` is equivalent to just `StockRequests.[StartYear] % StockIntervals.[IntervalInYears]  = @stockYear`

Comment: Which doesn't make much sense. Why are you trying to take the modulo of a *year* and compare it with another year? Where you trying to compare the year differences instead? The math expression is wrong then, because modulo (`%`) has higher precedence than subtraction. You'd have to write `(@stockYear - StockRequests.[StartYear])%StockIntervals.[IntervalInYears]` instead.

Comment: It's SQL Server and it is an EF problem, EF is switching the sides of the values in the generated query, without that switching the query works fine. The error still happens with a super simple query to select all `StockRequests` joining on the interval for the where clause, my code posted is from doing just that. So the complexity is irrelevant for solving the error.

Comment: No, the expression is wrong to begin with. You're dividing a year with an interval and comparing that with another year. This filter doesn't work to begin with. Even so, SQL Server shouldn't return different results. The order shouldn't matter.

Comment: I did that, just lost it when transposing from my code to SO. I have updated the posted code to show that. And your suggestion of `StockRequests.[StartYear] % StockIntervals.[IntervalInYears]  = @stockYear` still has you dividing by zero which still causes the error.

Comment: Again and again, that expression makes no sense. Why are you comparing 2022 with (2018%3)`? That expression will **never** produce any results.2018 will never be equal to 0, 1 or 2. And the sample data doesn't contain any zeroes either. I suspect there's a bigger problem with the query *and* the data

Comment: As I said, I did that and it was an error only in copying the code to SO. I DO have `0 = (@stockYear - StockRequests.[StartYear]) % StockIntervals.[IntervalInYears]`. which evaluates to 2021 - 2019 (2) % 2 for example. That still doesn't solve the error. You're saying the order doesn't matter but clearly it does, in SQL Server when I put: `0 <> StockIntervals.[IntervalInYears]`, divide by zero error, when I put: `StockIntervals.[IntervalInYears] <> 0` it works. my LINQ query appears like the second, but it converts to first.

Comment: In that case post actual data and a query that reproduces the problem. SQL Server shouldn't behave like this. The argument order doesn't matter. Post the `CREATE TABLE` expression, the `INSERT` statements and a query that fails the way you described

Comment: You made an extraordinary claim - that the order of the operators actually changes the execution plan in SQL Server. That requires extraordinary evidence: tables, data and a query that actually reproduces the problem. You said the query is 200 lines long so it's quite likely the problem is caused by the actual query instead of the example you posted

Comment: T-SQL has no notion of shortcutting boolean expressions. This means that, if there is *any* row such that `StockIntervals.[IntervalInYears]` is 0, the expression `StockIntervals.[IntervalInYears] <> 0  AND 0 = (@stockYear - StockRequests.[StartYear]) % StockIntervals.[IntervalInYears]` may give a division by zero error. This is true *regardless of how the operands are arranged*, so if it "happens to work" one way this is nothing more than coincidence. To make this reliable, something along the lines of `% NULLIF(StockIntervals.[IntervalInYears], 0)` or `CASE` should be used.

Comment: Since C# certainly does implement shortcutting, it could be argued EF should put in the effort to make this work, but clearly it doesn't, and I don't know how it should be compelled to do so. Perhaps chaining `.Where` expressions works (as opposed to putting it all in one condition).

Comment: @JeroenMostert using two tables with just the 4 rows in the OP's example doesn't cause a division by zero. But the execution plan shows that the modulo comparison occurs before the zero check, so this isn't about shortcutting - at least not documented shortcutting.

Comment: @SventoryMang what is the *exact* SQL Server version? [I can't reproduce the problem with those values](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1b506/2). I get back the two rows for 2020. I get no error in SQL Server 2019 either. *Maybe* the problem is how older, unsupported versions of SQL Server evaluated scalar conditions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I'm not particularly convinced the order of operations as shown in the execution plan is representative for what will actually happen either (when it's part of a compound predicate). Attempts at reliably repro'ing such things are notoriously difficult, since it may vary based on the usual -- actual contents of the table, whether parallelism is involved, cardinality, indexes, the phase of the moon. What I do know is that such evaluation order issues have routinely been closed in the past when reported as "won't fix", and defensive programming is the only way to fly.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The exact version is 12.0.5223.6. I'm working on providing what you requested. Also to note about complexity, even with no includes or select projections the error still occurs.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Can you elaborate why, if there is no shortcutting it works one way but not the other? Or how is it possible it can "may give the divide by zero error". Looking at the data, it's not because suddenly I have records where interval is 0. So no ordering on the query, no difference data, wouldn't the query hit the rows in the same order every time?

Comment: There might be all manner of reasons why: the order of joins might be different, the Expression Evaluation Service might evaluate `OR` expressions differently. You *cannot* rely on a calculation being short-circuited. **The only way to ensure order of evaluation is to use `CASE` or `NULLIF`** ([without aggregate functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks)). So in EF you would need to do something like `selectedYear - x.StartYear % (x.StockInterval.IntervalInYears == 0 ? null : x.StockInterval.IntervalInYears) == 0`

Comment: @Charlieface That worked, I did this: `(x.StockInterval.IntervalInYears != 0 && (year - x.StartYear) % (x.StockInterval.IntervalInYears == 0 ? (int?)null : x.StockInterval.IntervalInYears) == 0)` which evaluated to (for 2022): `(0 = ((2022 - [Request].[StartYear]) % (CASE WHEN (0 = [Interval].[IntervalInYears]) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE [Interval].[IntervalInYears] END)))`. And the results are the same as if I manually used my query with the operands switched: `StockIntervals.[IntervalInYears] <> 0`. So appears to be working, though why the switching works... Post an answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I've edited my post to include steps to reproduce it. I'm not sure how it could be called coincidence when I can reliably reproduce the behavior 100% of the time, both for erroring out and not erroring out. It appears in this case, at least with my version SQL, the order of the operand matters. No idea why. If there's no shortcutting, the mod should always evaluate as divide by zero if the result set has a interval 0 record. But it does not.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Edited my answer to get reproducible steps. I fixed the issue via LINQ per Charlieface's comment. But it doesn't seem to make sense that I can reliably always force the error, and resolve it by changing the order of the operands.

Comment: You can;t reliably force it: it just so happens that with a given set of circumstances that's what results. As you've shown, it's effectively arbitrary, because it depends on specific circumstances within the compiler and what it chooses when it optimizes

Comment: To clarify, by "coincidence" I don't mean the optimizer rolls a die every time it compiles the query, I mean that your reproduction, while reliable, is only reliable *for the specific case of your query*, that is, given the table contents, exact SQL server version, distribution of data, choice of parallelism etcetera etcetera. It is a coincidence in the sense that you could not expect other queries or other circumstances for the same query to behave the same way.  It is *not* a good idea to rely on this just because you've observed it to work a lot of times; it may fail six years from now.

Comment: And re: shortcutting (or rather "short-circuiting", didn't recall the right term): the engine is not guaranteed to short-circuit, but neither is it guaranteed to *not* short-circuit. It evaluates however it pleases. If it can prove short-circuiting would yield the same result barring errors, it *may* short-circuit for performance, but it is not guaranteed to do so (unlike in C#, where the compiler *must* evaluate `a && b` by *first* evaluating `a`, and then not evaluate `b` at all if `a` is `false` -- it can't choose to, say, evaluate `a` and `b` in parallel, while the optimizer *can*).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Could be wrong, but I'd be surprised if it ever did *not* short-circuit in the average case, because it's obviously less work to short-circuit. It's just that the *order* of short-circuiting is not guaranteed: `a && b` may become `b && a` but it's unlikely (although I agree not impossible or against the spec) for it to evaluate `a & b`. This doesn't take into account hitting indexes, subquery evaluation, and aggregation, obviously, where at least some part of both sides may get evaluated.

Comment: @Charlieface: it also doesn't take into account parallelism -- if the optimizer decides that `a` and `b` are more effectively evaluated in parallel, obviously it won't be able to apply short-circuiting logic (at least not effectively). Not an issue for this query in particular or indeed any expression of the form `column = constant AND <expression involving only column>` (because that should always be one seek/scan), but conjuring up other scenarios where both sides of the condition will get evaluated even where this is not apparently necessary is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You appear to be labouring under the assumption that `AND` and `OR` in T-SQL will always short-circuit in the order specified in the query. This is absolutely not the case.**

It is true that it will normally short-circuit a logical expression. After all, why do more work than necessary? But it may not be in the order that was specified in the query. Logical operators are not specified to execute in **any** particular order, and the optimizer often chooses to switch them around based on things like estimates of short-circuiting likelihood or the amount of work involved in evaluation, as long as the operator precedence rules are followed (`AND` before `OR` etc).

Because evaluating the space of all possible execution plans is too vast, the optimizer uses aggressive pruning to remove options based on heuristics. These two predicates:

```sql
(
    StockRequests.[StartYear] = @stockYear OR 
    (
        0 <> StockIntervals.[IntervalInYears]  AND 
        0 = (@stockYear - StockRequests.[StartYear]) % StockIntervals.[IntervalInYears] 
    )
)
```

and

```sql
(
    StockRequests.[StartYear] = @stockYear OR 
    (
        StockIntervals.[IntervalInYears] <> 0  AND 
        0 = (@stockYear - StockRequests.[StartYear]) % StockIntervals.[IntervalInYears] 
    )
)
```

are exactly the same as far as query intention is concerned. The question is what the optimizer will choose to do with them. In your case, it so happens that putting comparators one way around causes certain optimizations to fall in to place (or not) and therefore the `AND` can get flipped around.

**As you can see from [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=83f916f00944d208108c68f869a576e0),** which is running on SQL Server 2019, *both* of your options short-circuited correctly, as did flipping around the `AND`. I had to flip the `OR` to get it to fail, and then the order of the `AND` did not matter. Note that the logic was not changed in any of the queries, and that the order of the `AND`  or  `=` comparators themselves do not *force* the hand of the optimizer, it just sometimes guides it down a certain path.

So it's very dependent on what the optimizer decides to do, and you cannot *guarantee* upfront that it will always do it correctly. Yes, you saw it do that a hundred times, but the hundred-and-first could change, perhaps because of statistics changes, or a update to SQL Server, or changing the cardinality estimator version, or the database compatibility level, or any of the many things that can cause a recompile.

**The *only* guaranteed way** to ensure short-circuiting in a particular order is to use `CASE` (or `NULLIF` which compiles into a `CASE`). [This is documented by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks), it will work as long as you do not use any aggregation functions.

> In other words, do not expect something like `CASE WHEN x > 0 THEN SUM(1 / x) END` to work, because the `SUM` is often evaluated at an earlier stage. **It only works with scalar values.** As far as I am aware I would expect the same issue would apply to subqueries and window functions.

You can therefore work around your problem by using `NULLIF`

```sql
(
    StockRequests.[StartYear] = @stockYear OR 
    (
        StockIntervals.[IntervalInYears] <> 0  AND 
        0 = (@stockYear - StockRequests.[StartYear]) % NULLIF(StockIntervals.[IntervalInYears], 0)
    )
)
```

In Entity Framework you can use something like `(value == 0 ? null : value)`

```cs
query.Where(x => 
   x.StartYear <= selectedYear && 
  (
    x.StartYear == selectedYear || 
    (x.StockInterval.IntervalInYears != 0
     && selectedYear - x.StartYear %
        (x.StockInterval.IntervalInYears == 0 ? null : x.StockInterval.IntervalInYears)
        == 0) 
  )
);
```

Comment: You posted the same expression twice for the comparison, I assume you meant to write something different for the second time.

Comment: Thanks fixed. Do you agree with my analysis?

Comment: Yes, everything you said is fine. Except possibly the part about EF, I have little experience with it so I don't know if the expression translates correctly (but the OP can confirm that by accepting).

Comment: Thanks for your help and also @JeroenMostert too.